# How to add consonants to my keyboard with keyman

Tags: keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I'm trying to make a keyboard with keyman in which the consonants are included in the structure of the alphabet. That is, Ra is an extension of R. And the symbol to represent Ra is a modified version of the character R.
Something similar to Devnagari.

I know that one can use dead keys to modify the formating of a character. But I want functionality such that the  consonants are added after the characters.

I tried doing this by applying a dead key state to every character on the keyboard. Such that when you press a key, the keyboard will show the corresponding symbols for the consonants+character of the pressed key for you to choose from.
But this doesn't allow efficient typing. As you have to exit the dead key state everytime you press a key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to type a consonant, and then have it modified by the following keystroke.

This can be accomplished in Keyman by manipulating the context, for example, here I use 'R' as the consonant, and 'Ŕ' as the consonant with a vowel:

```
+ 'r' > 'R'
'R' + a' > 'Ŕ'
```

Pressing <kbd>r</kbd> will emit a `R`. The next keystroke, <kbd>a</kbd> will remove the `R` and replace it with `Ŕ`. This basic pattern illustrates how you can replace existing text with new output.

See https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/guide/rules for more information on how context and rules work.